# Convert this Linq code to regular/non linq code

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am new to Linq and working on someone's code  who was quite the opposite. He wrote this code below. I understand the code but can anyone tell me if i can convert this code to non linq in almost the same amount of code

```
public static AType MyFunction() 
{
          return new AType 
          {
              PropertyOfAType = SomeIEnumerable.Select(r => new BType
              {
                  Property1OfBType =  r.GetData(5),
                  Property2OfBType =  r.GetData(6)

              }).ToArray()
          };

}
```

Comment: Just use `Array.ConvertAll()`.

Comment: Sorry i dont see how Array.ConvertAll() will achieve the desired results. I am not converting one type of array to another. Can you write down the code ?

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll` is the same as `.Select()`, except that you need to convert the input to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static AType MyFunction()
    {
        AType aType = new AType();
        List<BType> bTypes = new List<BType>();
        foreach (var r in SomeIEnumerable)
        {
            bTypes.Add(new BType
            {
                Property1OfBType = r.GetData(5),
                Property2OfBType = r.GetData(6)
            });
        }
        aType.PropertyOfAType = bTypes.ToArray();
        return aType;
    }
```